# How to just call middleware one time in Django?

Tags: django-rest-framework

according to request's life cycle of django restful, middleware is called twice. Have any ways to just call it one time and skip to pass the response through middleware ?

Example: I have a middleware to check if the request's IP is in the allowed IP list and I want to call it one time when request is forwarded from gunicorn to django and skip middleware when return response to web server because it's unnecessary. I'm a Python's beginner so it look strange to me. Thank for your reading.

Comment: Where'd you get the idea it's *called twice*? Your middleware has two opportunities to modify something: once on the request, and once on the response. But that's just because of how it wraps around the request processing. Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware?

Comment: yeah, Maybe I made a mistake in the way I expressed it. I mean in the processing the request pass through middlewares twice and have some middleware, I want to request pass middleware once because the second is unnecessary. @deceze
https://learnbatta.com/course/django/request-response-lifecycle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware is simply a *function* that gets called, and which calls the next function in the chain. The sample from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware):

> ```
> def simple_middleware(get_response):
>     # One-time configuration and initialization.
>
>     def middleware(request):
>         # Code to be executed for each request before
>         # the view (and later middleware) are called.
>
>         response = get_response(request)
>
>         # Code to be executed for each request/response after
>         # the view is called.
>
>         return response
>
>     return middleware
> ```

Your middleware doesn't get called twice. It gets called once. And it *can* call the next middleware in the chain or not; and it's expected to return a response, either from itself or from the next middleware in the chain.

If you do call the next middleware in the chain, then the execution will necessarily pass through your middleware twice. Once when it gets called, and again when the next middleware you called returns its response. If you don't want to do anything then, then simply don't. E.g.:

```
def simple_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        # do something here

        return get_response(request)

    return middleware
```

That's as minimal as you can make it. There's no way to not pass the response through your middleware, but that really shouldn't be any concern when written like above.